# fetching Json swift 5

Tags: json, swift, xcode, rest, swift5

im trying to fetch some data from my api in swift 5

I get this error

> Member 'success' in 'Result<[Suggestion], SuggestionError>' produces result of type 'Result', but context expects 'Result<[Suggestion],

and this is the function that gives me problems. if I comment the line giving me trouples it prints canNotProcessData

```
func getSuggestions (completion: @escaping(Result<[Suggestion], SuggestionError>) -> Void){
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resourceURL) { data, response, error in
        guard let jsonData = data else{
            completion(.failure(.noDataAvailable))
            return
        }
        print(response!)
        do{
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let suggestionReponse = try decoder.decode(Suggestion.self, from: jsonData)
            let suggestions = suggestionReponse

            completion(.success(Suggestion))

        }catch{
            completion(.failure(.canNotProcessData))
        }

    }
    dataTask.resume()  
}
```

and this is my Suggestion struct

```
struct Suggestion:Decodable{
    var id: Int
    var hometeam: String
    var awayteam: String
    var hometeamLogo: String
    var awayteamLogo: String
    var bet: String
    var value: Double
    var stake: Int
    var bookieOdds: Double
}
```

and this is an example of what I receive from my api

```
[
    {
        "id": 132,
        "hometeam": "Afjet Afyonspor",
        "awayteam": "Sancaktepe Belediyespor",
        "hometeamLogo": "https://media.api-football.com/teams/3565.png",
        "awayteamLogo": "https://media.api-football.com/teams/3604.png",
        "bet": "2",
        "value": 1.19,
        "stake": 1,
        "bookieOdds": 2.55
    },

    {
        "id": 152,
        "hometeam": "Bolívar",
        "awayteam": "Blooming",
        "hometeamLogo": "https://media.api-football.com/teams/3702.png",
        "awayteamLogo": "https://media.api-football.com/teams/3701.png",
        "bet": "2",
        "value": 3.18,
        "stake": 1,
        "bookieOdds": 11
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better show the whole message precisely:

> ```
> Member 'success' in 'Result<[Suggestion], SuggestionError>' produces
> result of type 'Result<Success, Failure>', but context expects
> 'Result<[Suggestion], SuggestionError>'
> ```

And it is obviously wrong as you are passing a type name here:

```
            completion(.success(Suggestion))
```

But before the line, you have one thing wrong:

```
            let suggestionReponse = try decoder.decode(Suggestion.self, from: jsonData)
```

The outermost structure of your JSON response is an array (`[` ... `]`) and you need to decode it as an `Array` of `Suggestion`s, not a `Suggestion`:

Please try something like this:

```
    func getSuggestions(completion: @escaping(Result<[Suggestion], SuggestionError>) -> Void){
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resourceURL) { data, response, error in
            guard let jsonData = data else{
                completion(.failure(.noDataAvailable))
                return
            }
            print(response!)
            do{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                //### Use `[Suggestion].self`, not `Suggestion.self`
                let suggestions = try decoder.decode([Suggestion].self, from: jsonData)
                completion(.success(suggestions)) //###Use the response, not the type name
            } catch {
                print(error) //### This gives you some hints on how to solve the error cases
                completion(.failure(.canNotProcessData))
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

Comment: just tried changing it to [Suggestion].self but it made no difference. The error message is complete, copied it directly from Xcode

Comment: @sebbelebbe, I have tested this code with your _an example_. If it does not work, you are not testing it properly. And compare the error messages yours and mine. Your error message lacks the last part. Do you really want to solve your issue?

Comment: @sebbelebbe you can’t just change one thing since your code contains multiple errors so read this answer again and make sure you include all changes in your code